# How to write uploaded file to a given location in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I found the following in Django doc.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

If name.txt doesn't exist in the directory, will it get created? 
Do I save the 'some/file/name.txt' string in FileField in django model?

Comment: the `'wb+'` part (specifically the `+`) when opening the file handle ensures it will be created if it doesn't exist

Comment: thanks! I should have known it's a unix command.
Do I save the url of the file to the django model FileField ?

Comment: if you're using a `FileField` you don't need a `handle_uploaded_file` function, just specify the `upload_to` attribute of the field as either a constant or a callable https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> w+ or wb+
> ```
>
> Truncate to zero length or create file for update.

So yes if file doesn't exist it will get Created